# ratios by row in R

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I'm using R to analyze a survey. An example dataframe is depicted below. I'd like to create two new columns in the DF. The first, called DF$ratio, should find the ratio of the number of TRUE to FALSE for each group. So row two of the new column, for example, should be 0.676 (23/34) and row four should be 0.622 (204/328). The second, called DF$ratio2, should be the ratio of the number of TRUE to the sum of TRUE and FALSE for each group. So row two of the new column, for example, should be 0.404 (23/(23+34)). I'm new to R. Is there an easy way to generate these new columns? Thanks!

```
   accept                         group number
1   FALSE                 Very positive     34
2    TRUE                 Very positive     23
3   FALSE             Somewhat positive    328
4    TRUE             Somewhat positive    204
5   FALSE Neither positive nor negative    469
6    TRUE Neither positive nor negative    207
7   FALSE             Somewhat negative    225
8    TRUE             Somewhat negative    111
9   FALSE                 Very negative     76
10   TRUE                 Very negative     34
11  FALSE           Not Sure/Don’t Know    306
12   TRUE           Not Sure/Don’t Know     63
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to reshape your data:

```
DF <- read.table(text='   accept                         group number
1   FALSE                 "Very positive"     34
2    TRUE                 "Very positive"     23
3   FALSE             "Somewhat positive"    328
4    TRUE             "Somewhat positive"    204
5   FALSE "Neither positive nor negative"    469
6    TRUE "Neither positive nor negative"    207
7   FALSE             "Somewhat negative"    225
8    TRUE             "Somewhat negative"    111
9   FALSE                 "Very negative"     76
10   TRUE                 "Very negative"     34
11  FALSE           "Not Sure/Don’t Know"    306
12   TRUE           "Not Sure/Don’t Know"     63', header=TRUE)

library(reshape2)
DF.wide <- dcast(DF, group ~ accept, value.var="number")

DF.wide$ratio <- DF.wide[["TRUE"]]/DF.wide[["FALSE"]]
DF.wide$ratio2 <- DF.wide[["TRUE"]]/(DF.wide[["TRUE"]] + DF.wide[["FALSE"]])
#                           group FALSE TRUE     ratio    ratio2
# 1 Neither positive nor negative   469  207 0.4413646 0.3062130
# 2           Not Sure/Don’t Know   306   63 0.2058824 0.1707317
# 3             Somewhat negative   225  111 0.4933333 0.3303571
# 4             Somewhat positive   328  204 0.6219512 0.3834586
# 5                 Very negative    76   34 0.4473684 0.3090909
# 6                 Very positive    34   23 0.6764706 0.4035088
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
    group_by(group) %>% 
    mutate(ratio=number[accept]/number[!accept],
               ratio2=number[accept]/sum(number))
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[,c('ratio', 'ratio2'):= list(number[accept]/number[!accept], 
              ratio2=number[accept]/sum(number)) , by=group]
```

Or if we assume that there are two `rows` per `group` and it is ordered as `FALSE`, `TRUE`, and you wanted to fill `NA` in `ratio`, `ratio2` columns for rows with `accept=FALSE`

```
 DF$ratio[DF$accept] <- with(DF, number[accept]/number[!accept])
 DF$ratio2[DF$accept] <- with(DF, number[accept]/(number[!accept]+
                                                    number[accept]))     
  DF
  #   accept                         group number     ratio    ratio2
  #1   FALSE                 Very positive     34        NA        NA
  #2    TRUE                 Very positive     23 0.6764706 0.4035088
  #3   FALSE             Somewhat positive    328        NA        NA
  #4    TRUE             Somewhat positive    204 0.6219512 0.3834586
  #5   FALSE Neither positive nor negative    469        NA        NA
  #6    TRUE Neither positive nor negative    207 0.4413646 0.3062130
  #7   FALSE             Somewhat negative    225        NA        NA
  #8    TRUE             Somewhat negative    111 0.4933333 0.3303571
  #9   FALSE                 Very negative     76        NA        NA
  #10   TRUE                 Very negative     34 0.4473684 0.3090909
  #11  FALSE           Not Sure/Don’t Know    306        NA        NA
  #12   TRUE           Not Sure/Don’t Know     63 0.2058824 0.1707317
```

Answer (score 0):

Ratio 1:

```
DF$ratio[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- DF$number[c(FALSE, TRUE)] / DF$number[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
```

Ratio 2:

```
DF$ratio2[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- DF$number[c(FALSE, TRUE)] / (DF$number[c(TRUE, FALSE)]+DF$number[c(FALSE,TRUE)])
```

Comment: I get the same values repeated by using this method along with the warnings.